# Document convert with Libreoffice on Linux using either shell or PHP hangs up

Tags: php, linux, bash, libreoffice

I'm trying to create a website that converts uploaded .docx files into HTML. As part of the process, I also convert the .docx to PDF and then convert the PDF to an image so that I can obtain a thumbnail of the .docx file. The final solution has all security concerns taken care off, right now this is just a bare bones R&D effort to get the conversion working.

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf "/var/www/upload/orgchart.docx" --outdir /var/www/upload/
convert -quality 100 -alpha remove -background white -thumbnail x480 "/var/www/upload/orgchart.pdf"[0] "/var/www/thumbnails/orgchart.jpg"
libreoffice --headless "/var/www/upload/orgchart.docx" --convert-to html --outdir "/var/www/upload/orgchart.html"
```

If I put these commands into a PHP script as follows:

```
<?php

$sourceFilePath = "/var/www/upload/orgchart.docx";
$tempPDFFilePath = "/var/www/upload/orgchart.pdf";
$tempImageFilePath = "/var/www/thumbnails/orgchart.jpg";

$cmdLine1 = "libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf \"{$sourceFilePath}\" --outdir /var/www/upload/";
exec($cmdLine1);
$cmdLine2 = "convert -quality 100 -alpha remove -background white -thumbnail x480 \"$tempPDFFilePath\"[0] \"$tempImageFilePath\"";
exec($cmdLine2);
$cmdLine3 = "libreoffice --headless \"{$sourceFilePath}\" --convert-to html --outdir /var/www/upload/";
exec($cmdLine3);

echo "done";

?>
```

The PHP script hangs. I've tried appending `> /dev/null 2>&1` to each command line but it still hangs up. I can see the first libreoffice instance running as a process if I use `ps -aux | grep "libre"`

I then decided to remove PHP from the process and I created a bash script using the original three commands:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf "/var/www/upload/orgchart.docx" --outdir /var/www/upload/
convert -quality 100 -alpha remove -background white -thumbnail x480 "/var/www/upload/orgchart.pdf"[0] "/var/www/thumbnails/orgchart.jpg"
libreoffice --headless "/var/www/upload/orgchart.docx" --convert-to html --outdir "/var/www/upload/orgchart.html"
```

The bash script also hangs. If I use paste each command separately into the command line, it works 100%.

If I use the php CLI interface to execute the PHP script, it works 100%. So I know it's not a path issue, both PHP and the shell are able to find and execute libreoffice.

Any ideas and suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I see the post have 2 years old... have you any solution ?

Comment: @jintor Hey I'm afraid not, the project was cancelled before a solution was found.

Comment: I found an alternative, see answer

Answer (score 0):

I find an alternative

```
unoconv -e PageRange=1 --export Quality=100 -f pdf path_to.docx
```